# onclick event. blur and 2 window > Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, events, cookies, onclick

I need a code to redirect the User to another window, through an onclick event. I want the redirect to happen twice a day, and when there is a new window should open behind, like the pirate bay.

I have this code, it opens only once and in front of the main window.

What can we do?

Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- INICIO DO CÓDIGO -->
<script>
    function PopShow3() {
        var wn = window.open( & quot; & quot;, & quot; PopWin3 & quot;, & quot; width = & quot; + screen.width + & quot;, height = & quot; + screen.height + & quot;, resizable = 1, toolbar = 1, location = 0, menubar = 0, status = 1, scrollbars = 1 & #39;&quot;
                                              );wn.location.href= & #39;http://google.com/&# 39;; wn.focus(); document.onmouseup = & quot; & quot;;
        }
        var cookieString = document.cookie;
        var start = cookieString.indexOf( & quot; kmr9eE1 = & quot;);
        if (start == -1) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 1000);
            document.cookie = & quot;
            kmr9eE1 = update;
            expires = & quot; + expires.toGMTString();
            document.onmouseup = PopShow3;
        }
</script>
<!-- FIM DO CÓDIGO -->
```

Comment: *(..) redirect (..) through an onclick event (..) twice a day*. Does it mean that you want to control your visitors' mind to click twice a day in your page? If not, I don't see how both constraints could be fulfilled.

Comment: My English is terrible. My site has 25,000 visitors per day. and they click on average six times per section. I only want two of these clicks to open other pages donations to UNICEF and the UN. Can you help me?

Comment: When you say *two of these clicks*, do you mean the first and the second, or which ones?